# How to define a "digital" sellable item in Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

### Question

I am trying to create a Digital based product in `Sitecore Commerce`, where the product can be fulfilled via digital means (e.g email).

Based on my testing via postman using `Habitat` Catalog(see below), it appears that a fulfillment type for a cart is directly related to the Sellable items added on the cart.

But in the Sitecore Commerce Business tool, I can't find a way to configure the sellable item's fulfillment type/options to digital.

Does anyone know how the logic works and how to configure it? Thanks in advance

### Testing via Postman

#### 1. Digital Product Example

**1a. Postman - Add Cart Line with Variant**
Product: `Habitat_Master|6042986|56042986 -- Habitat Gift Cards ($25)`

Url: `{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/AddCartLine()`

Body:

```
{
    "cartId":"TestCart01",
    "itemId": "Habitat_Master|6042986|56042986",
    "quantity": 1
}
```

**1b. Postman - Get cart fulfillment options**

Url: `{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/GetCartFulfillmentOptions(cartId='TestCart01')`

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5000/Api/$metadata#FulfillmentOptions",
    "value": [
        {
            "CompositeKey": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null,
            "DateCreated": "2019-06-27T03:24:56.3161735Z",
            "DateUpdated": "2019-06-27T03:24:56.3161735Z",
            "DisplayName": "Digital",
            "FriendlyId": null,
            "Id": "3878b502-85ac-41b5-9203-e0f8712a854b",
            "Version": 0,
            "EntityVersion": 1,
            "Published": true,
            "IsPersisted": false,
            "Name": "Digital",
            "Policies": [],
            "FulfillmentType": "Digital",
            "Enabled": false,
            "Provider": null,
            "CostType": null,
            "Cost": null
        }
    ]
}
```

#### 2. Physical Product Example

**2a. Postman - Add Cart Line with Variant**

Product: `Habitat_Master|6042963|56042963 -- Habitat Sentinel Touchscreen Thermostat`

Url: `{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/AddCartLine()`

Body:

```
{
    "cartId":"TestCart02",
    "itemId": "Habitat_Master|6042963|56042963",
    "quantity": 1
}
```

**2b. Postman - Get cart fulfillment options**

Url: `{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/GetCartFulfillmentOptions(cartId='TestCart02')`

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5000/Api/$metadata#FulfillmentOptions",
    "value": [
        {
            "CompositeKey": null,
            "CreatedBy": null,
            "UpdatedBy": null,
            "DateCreated": "2019-06-27T03:24:56.3421052Z",
            "DateUpdated": "2019-06-27T03:24:56.3421052Z",
            "DisplayName": "Ship items",
            "FriendlyId": null,
            "Id": "3817f8d5-994b-4fbc-8bbe-4c342ec7553a",
            "Version": 0,
            "EntityVersion": 1,
            "Published": true,
            "IsPersisted": false,
            "Name": "Ship items",
            "Policies": [],
            "FulfillmentType": "ShipToMe",
            "Enabled": false,
            "Provider": null,
            "CostType": null,
            "Cost": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to mark your product as digital, you need to add any tag to the product or product variant from list below:

- OnlineTraining
- OnlineLearning
- Subscription
- DigitalSubscription

Read my blog post about that:

https://www.brimit.com/blog/sitecore-commerce-9-how-to-override-policy